# 800A0E7A - “Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed”

Tags: sql, access, office, oledb

При попытке запустить скрипт vbs вылетает ошибка:

800A0E7A - “Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed”

Система х64, все дрова стоят для х32.

Пытаюсь использовать такой провайдер:

"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"